# collapse/expand text - logic error

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script that will get executed when i click a button. When the button is clicked the text below will collapse and when i click on the button again the text will be expanded and viewed.

But, what i want is the opposite. When the page loads it self i want to hide/collapse the text and only display upon clicking on the button.

How can i make that change?

JS

```
function toggleMe(a) {
                var e = document.getElementById(a);
                if (!e)
                    return true;
                if (e.style.display == "none") {
                    e.style.display = "block"
                } else {
                    e.style.display = "none"
                }
                return true;
            }
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" ="return toggleMe('para1')" value="Toggle">
                <br>
                <p id="para1">
                    some text................ </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function toggleMe(a) {
                var e = document.getElementById(a);
                if (!e)
                    return true;
                if (e.style.display == "none") {
                    e.style.display = "block"
                } else {
                    e.style.display = "none"
                }
                return true;
            }
</script>

<body>
<input type="button" onclick="toggleMe('para1')" value="Toggle">
                <br>
                <p id="para1" style="display:none;">
                    some text................ </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I only want to hide all text onLoad, and display the text when the button is clicked. But in your method, i am not able to display the text when i click the button.

Comment: Nothing hapense, its the same as before :(

Comment: May be with the addition of `<p id="para1" style="display: none">` it works.

Comment: just copy the code into a new file and run it, It should work, then you can compare it with your own file

Answer (score 1):

change

```
        <p id="para1">
to
        <p id="para1" style="display: none">
```

Does this works ?

Comment: I only want to hide all text onLoad, and display the text when the button is clicked. But in your method, i am not able to display the text when i click the button.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont't you hide the text on window load?

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById("para1").style.display = "none";

}
```

Or you can type into your html

```
<p id="para1" style="display: none">
                some text................ 
</p>
```

Comment: It disappears, but i don't see the text displayed when i click the button